# How to remove the border line in a div-CSS

Tags: html, css, border

I'm using the following css to style a div:

```
.mod head-update{
    height: 40px;
    border-style: none!important;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Yet I get 2 grey lines at the top and bottom of the div.
How can I remove it?

Comment: I think some other elements/classes are over writing yours. Can you provide more information with HTML and CSS or some fiddle link?

Comment: It seems likely that you're missing `#` or `.` before `head-update`. Please can you post your HTML so we can see a reproducible example?

Comment: Please use the browsers element inspectors. Press [F12] and feel the power!

Comment: @Hidden Hobbes- you are right! 10x!

Answer (score 18):

<sub>You should most probably fix your selector `head-update` with a class `.` or ID `#` like: `.head-update` (or `#head-update` ?)</sub>

Try with

```
border: none !important;
```

(P.S note the space between `none` and `!important`)

**WARNING!**
`!important` should never be used — unless you're cornered but you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: **Noooo**! Not `!important`. At any way try to avoid using it.

Comment: I mostly agree. `!important` is sign of poor CSS coding and  selectors *Specificity*. (Though in some rare cases it's a *necessity diamond*)

Comment: @Sarti please show the minimal HTML + CSS to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Sarti have you fixed your selector as suggested?

Comment: @Roko C.Buljan- yes Roko.

Comment: @Sarti still waiting for some HTML

Comment: @Roko C.Buljan- there is no need. The problem was exactly what Hidden Hobbes wrote.

Answer (score 2):

Without testing it myself, here's how I would modify the borders there, like others say...

```
border: none !important;
```

And uunless you want something to try and override it, I would get rid of `!important`.

Another thing I would do is try to state the `background-color`.

```
background-color: #FFFFFF;
```

And, if you don't have too many of the element and you don't mind a `style` attribute on your tag, you could possibly do this, which should override any CSS rules that go against it...

```
<div class="..." style="border:none; background-color:white"></div>
```

There could be a background of gray somehow and another element inside the div that has a background-color of white. With the padding, that would cause there to be some space above the inner-lying white `div` and the parent `div` (the one your trying to fix) could somehow get a background-color of gray from something.

Comment: `style="border:none; background-color:white"` worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, `outline: none;`

```
.mod head-update{
    height: 40px;
    border-style: none!important;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;

    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : )

```css
margin: -8px;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by making the same background color for the container div  as below.

```
<div class="row" style="width: 100%;background-color: #250505;">
    <div style="background-color: #250505; width: 10%;float:left;font-size: 32px;border: none !important; ">
    content .........
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:center;font-size:2.2vh;color:rgb(255, 255, 255); width:80%; font-weight:700;background-color: #250505;">
      content .....................
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #250505; width: 10%;float:right;font-size: 32px; border: none !important;">
      content .............
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

change

```
border-style: none!important;
```

to

```
border : none !important;
```

Comment: Could you explain the enhancement over @RokoC.Buljan's answer?